# Do JavaScript ES6 classes violate functional programming style?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

I've been unconsciously incorporating functional approaches in my JavaScript code, but still struggle to be clear on some aspects. I am confused about how to manage some immutable state without using  classes.

For instance, here is a class I've used:

```js
class User {

    constructor(id) {
        this._ref = db.collection(..).doc(id)
    }

    getUserData = async => {
        const data = await this._ref.get()
        return data.map(doc => {
            // some transformation
        })
    }

    // .. other functions that use the ref

}
```

None of the class methods mutate the ref.

My question is whether usage of a class is poor functional programming practice? If so, what are the standard alternative approaches? I can think of passing the ID as an additional parameter to every function. I have also looked into currying. Thank you!

Comment: Seem to be comparing apples and oranges in your question.

Comment: Well yes, because classes are the corner stone of OOP. Javascript is multi paradigm though and this is probably the greatest weakness of the language, because mixing paradigms is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. You can use classes to make functional programming easier. In this case the oop code becomes an implementation detail. It can also be an optimization technique as all the instances of the class can all use the same instances of the functions in the class.

If you want the syntactic terseness of pure fp then oop will always get in the way but if you just want your code to be predictable/testable then it doesnt have to be the dominant paradigm in your codebase. Many functional libraries use classes under the hood.

However the code you posted looks like oop code to me. why have _ref at all? The class is just noise. The only thing happening here is

```
const getUserData = async (id) => {
    const data = await db.collection(..).doc(id);
    return data.map(doc => {
        // some transformation
    })
}
```

which is probably better off as

```
const getUserData = (id) => db.collection(..).doc(id)
    .then((data) => 
        data.map(doc => {
        // some transformation
        }
    );
```

notice you can use the .then method on the promise class to avoid the imperative async/await syntax